# Throwing custom exception in console application

Tags: c#, throw, argumentexception

so I'm trying to catch a custom exception. It works fine but skips to the next line of the code without giving me a chance to retry. If I try it without a try-catch block it still works but terminates the program. I'd like for it to catch the custom exception then allow me to enter the correct input value. Thanks

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter User Name: ");

        try
        {
            
            user.userName = Console.ReadLine();
            
            if(user.userName != "Papa")
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("User name doesn't exist");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }



       try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter User Pin: ");
            user.userPin = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Where is your retry logic? Your catch simply writes the error messages and moves on.

Comment: I'm still new to programming I admit I did not know I needed a retry. Could you assist me? Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't use exceptions to control program flow. For your `throw new ArgumentException("User name doesn't exist");`  you should just write `Console.WriteLine("User name doesn't exist");`. Avoid exception handlers where possible. They hide actual errors, make your program slow, and make understanding your program more difficult.

Answer (score 2):

'try' does not mean 'keep trying until no exception'. It just means 'do this and if there is an exception go there'. You have to write a loop yourself

```
while (true) //loop till 'break'
{ 
    try
    {
        user.userName = Console.ReadLine();
        if (user.userName != "Papa")
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("User name doesn't exist");
        }
        break; //input is good - so break out of loop
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

I would also say that I really dont like using an exception like that, to take a different logic path in side a single function. I would do

```
while (true)
{
    user.userName = Console.ReadLine();
    if (user.userName == "Papa")
    {
        break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Bad user name");
}
```

Comment: Using a while true and then breaking it is a sign that you are not writing clean code!

Comment: I mean create a bool that is set to true where your "breaks" is. Is not more difficult, but more cleanly programmed.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use exceptions to control program flow. For your `throw new ArgumentException("User name doesn't exist");` you should just write `Console.WriteLine("User name doesn't exist");`. Avoid exception handlers where possible. They hide actual errors, make your program slow, and make understanding your program more difficult.

Here's how I would write your code to avoid exception handlers:

```
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter User Name: ");
    user.Name = Console.ReadLine();
    if (user.Name == "Papa")
    {
        break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("User name doesn't exist");
}

while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter User Pin: ");
    if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int pin))
    {
        user.Pin = pin;
        break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Pin");
}
```